# How to Show MySQL Enums Value in JCombobox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, enums, jcombobox

This is a table that I created called `msemployee`. contains the column position type data enums (with values: admin, chef, cashier).

[image: this is a table that I created called <code>msemployee</code>. contains the column position type data enums (with values: admin, chef, cashier).]

This is the `JComboBox` that I made. and this combo box I want to fill in with the value of the "position" column. so, in the first item from combo box I want to fill it by taking the value "admin" from the column "position" earlier. as well as the second and third combo box items.

Does Anyone know how? I have tried but never succeeded.

[image]

Comment: [Are enums supported by JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155967/are-enums-supported-by-jdbc) might somewhere to start

Comment: I don't really understand. details please.

Comment: The "basic" problem is - there's no way to get the range values which the column supports through raw JDCB alone - so, unless you're willing to restrict the possible selection on the UI side, you're going to have a very hard time making it work.  Maybe a traditional two table relationship would be easier

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: A more traditional approach would have a second table of valid items and then you'd create a one to many relationship between the two.  This way, you could load the list of valid items from the child table